# Magic Puzzle won't work after I downloaded an update to it, can I uninstall the update

Tags: ipad, software-update

Magic Puzzle won't work after I downloaded an update to it on my IPad, can I uninstall the update. I don't like the update, it doesn't play right, I want to go back to the one I had before.

Comment: afaik if you don't have a Backup bevore the update - there is no way to "downgrade" an App

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the old ipa in your iTunes library, you can install that on your device. Delete the new app from your device, the connect your device to iTunes, select the app and sync.